# When minifyEnabled is true ,how to convert JSON String to Custom Object?

Tags: android, json, apk, minify

My Android app uses an API to get a JSON string and want to cast it to a custom object.

When minifyEnabled is false, it works well but when set to true and make an APK, after doing some testing I found that Gson can not map the JSONObject string to my customer object and all the properties are null.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);// result is a string that have got from the API
Gson gson = new Gson();
String v=String.valueOf(obj);
MyObjectModel mobj= gson.fromJson(v,MyObjectModel.class);//Null Execption happen here
String t=goodMoodContentModel.getContentText();//t is null when minifyEnabled is true
```

Why this happens and how to handle it?

**UPDATE:**

I used  this codes to test it:

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried preserving the class in your pro-guard rules (-keep ETC) ?

Comment: Can you explain it more plz? As you can see  in the update,  useProguard =false

Comment: Your update shows the debug config. You mentioned you were building an apk, so you should specify a "release" build type in your build.gradle